# Float mapping precision with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to store a float in a MySQL database but Hibernate gets a differente value than what is stored in the column,

In my app I calculate:

```
float subtotal = 160.5f;
float ammount = (float) (subtotal * 0.1f); // this way I get the 10%
receipt.setAmmount(ammount);
receipt.save();
```

If I log that ammount I get something like this:

```
19/04/2013 10:17:20 [INFO] ServiceImpl: Added ammount x $16.05
```

My column `ammount` in the mysql db is `FLOAT UNSIGNED` and when I do a select I obtain 16.05 as the value but later, when I fetch that object with Hibernate the ammount field is 16.049999237060547.

My hbm column looks like this:

```
<property name="ammount" type="float"></property>
```

I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399401/hibernate-and-currency-precision) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal) that is recommended to use `BigDecimal` in Java instead of `Float` or `Double` for money, but I can't get what data type should I use in my database or how to config Hibernate to use that datatype, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The recommended Java mapping for the DECIMAL and NUMERIC types is
>   java.math.BigDecimal. The java.math.BigDecimal type provides math
>   operations to allow BigDecimal types to be added, subtracted,
>   multiplied, and divided with other BigDecimal types, with integer
>   types, and with floating point types.
>
> The method recommended for retrieving DECIMAL and NUMERIC values is
>   ResultSet.getBigDecimal. JDBC also allows access to these SQL types as
>   simple Strings or arrays of char. Thus, Java programmers can use
>   getString to receive a DECIMAL or NUMERIC result. However, this makes
>   the common case where DECIMAL or NUMERIC are used for currency values

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550337/what-type-would-you-map-bigdecimal-in-java-hibernate-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd try defining your column as NUMBER(6,2) on the database and using a BigDecimal object in your java layer. You should not be using float for currencies.