# Issue with migration from float to decimal in mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, migration

We have stored money as float type in mysql with out defining precision or scale. We realized that money should not be stored as float but decimal with precision and scale should be used. Now we have defined Decimal(16,6) to store same values.

Now when we migrated from float to decimal, we are seeing unwanted numbers.
For example: from application a value entered as 0.45 is stored as 0.45003456 float type. When we migrating to decimal it is getting stored as 0.450034.

Question: So, is there a way to retrieve the original value entered which is 0.45? and migrate the same.

Note: In application we are using hibernate which is showing correct values as 0.45 and not 0.45003456 [we have defined as float in hibernate mapping for this column]

Answer (score 0):

No, precision was permanently lost *on insertion*, there is no way to recover lost information *with the database only*.

I am guessing the precision was lost by your ORM, since the behaviour you describe does not show when manipulating the database directly:

```
CREATE TABLE t_source (
    v FLOAT
);
CREATE TABLE t_target (
    v DECIMAL(16,6)
);
INSERT INTO t_source VALUE (0.45);
SELECT * FROM t_source; -- result: 0.45
INSERT INTO t_target SELECT * FROM t_source;
ALTER TABLE t_source MODIFY COLUMN v DECIMAL(16,6);
SELECT * FROM t_source; -- result: 0.450000
SELECT * FROM t_target; -- result: 0.450000
```

Since your ORM layer seems to *alter* the stored values *back to their original value* when reading from the database, I would try to convert the values through this ORM.

---

*Note: it looks like the `DECIMAL` database type should map to the `java.math.BigDecimal` Java type, [but I have no idea what I am talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16105903/1446005). The below may or may not work.*

1. add a new decimal column to your table
2. map this new column as a `BigDecimal`
3. for each row

   - read the existing value through the ORM
   - write the value into the new column through the ORM
4. drop the old column